# How to replace string in different position in sentence by another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have problem how to replace string in another position than 0 in sentence using my function.

I want to replace string in col2 from string in col1 (always lowercase)

For example I want try replace:

```
input: Hello Aaa1 my very good friend
output: Hello NNP my very good friend
```

Now I have only:

```
input: Aaa1 my very good friend
output: NNP my very good friend
```

I want to replace string in all position of sentence.

I try:

```
## import libraries
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, pos_tag_sents

## tag the sentece
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(word_tokenize).apply(pos_tag)

## this function does the magic 
def get_vals(lst):
    op = [] 
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        if i == 0:
            op.append(v[1])
        else:
            op.append(v[0])
    return ' '.join(op)

## apply the function
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(get_vals)

print(df)

   col1                      col2
0  aaa1     NNP is a great friend
1  abb2  NN is a very good friend
```

Edit:

I have:

```
col1           col2                output
aaa1          AAA1 Hello hello     NNP Hello hello
aaa2          aaa2 hello hello     NN hello hello
aaa3          Hello AAa3 hello     Hello NNP hello
```

I want to replace in each row with specific POS Tag (not only one string for NNP)

Answer (score 0):

Using re

```
import re
inp = "Hello Aaa1 my very good friend"
output = "Hello NNP my very good friend"

re.sub("Aaa1", "NNP", output)
```

Using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col": [inp]})
df["col"].str.replace("Aaa1", "NNP")
```

Comment: Why is `aaa2` `NN` then? `pos_tag` tags it as `JJ`?

Comment: it's only example. pos_tag must tagging oryginal words for example: NN, NNP, JJ etc. by word from col1 in sentence with different letter case (AAA1, aaa1, AaAa1 etc.)

Comment: you know how to do it?