# Replace string in sentence using another column and POS tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to replace string in sentence using another column and POS tag?

I want to replace string in col2 as POS tag from col1

For example:

```
col1    col2                           output
mtmb2   MTMB2 is a my sentence         NNP is a my sentence
mmm2    Your MmM2 is my sentence       Your NNP is my sentence
bbb2    Your sentence is bbb2          Your sentence is NN
```

I try use @YOLO solution:

```
## import libraries
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, pos_tag_sents

## tag the sentece
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(word_tokenize).apply(pos_tag)

## this function does the magic 
def get_vals(lst):
    op = [] 
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        if i == 0:
            op.append(v[1])
        else:
            op.append(v[0])
    return ' '.join(op)

## apply the function
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(get_vals)

print(df)

   col1                      col2
0  aaa1     NNP is a great friend
1  abb2  NN is a very good friend
```

But this solution working only if word to replace is on first index...

Comment: Practically the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/50085252? (And a whole lot of likewise questions – your classmates?)

Comment: @usr2564301 Yes, but this solution doesn't working if i check it. This solution only replace one string to another. I Want to replace string from col1 and tag them in col2

Comment: Desired output?

Comment: @HarvIpan Desired output look at Example in my post above